# Queue conflicts when multithreading?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to put together a very simple multithreading model, and so far it seems to work. My question is how am I sure that two threads will not grab the same value from the queue simultaneously and give me repeats? Is there just some built in method that prevents this? I added a delay to try to put time between when each thread will get a value from the queue, is this necessary?

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

class myThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):       
        while True:                      
            time.sleep(0.0001)   #not sure if this is good enough to compensate for overlap in pulling the same value out of a queue         
            task = self.queue.get() #pull a number from the queue,
            if task != None:          
                out.append(task) #This will be where you        
            else:               
                break


queue = Queue()
out = []


for i in range(10):
    t = myThread(queue)
    t.start()
for i in range(100):
    queue.put(i)
print out
```

Comment: The queue already implement locking mechanisms so that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Queue class implements locking to prevent this happening, see http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html, in particular:

> It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must
>   be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this
>   module implements all the required locking semantics.

So you don't need any delay, the queue should work exactly as you want.  That's what it was written for (basically) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You code are correct. The sleep do not is necessary. The Queue is [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29). Exist a lock that avoid threads to pull the same task.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of queue.Queue is that it guarantees this property for you. No sleep is needed (and sleeping is never a good way around concurrency glitches).